# Ignore duplicate data id in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I ignore duplicate data ids from query SQL results:

In this case I tried to combine several tables. Like this scheme that I made:

```sql
Transactions
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id
user_id
type
amount
invoice_transaction (Relation to invoice)
created_at
updated_at
```

```sql
Users
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id
name
email
phone
birth
address
picture
created_at
updated_at
```

```sql
Vouchers
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id
code
amount
type
created_at
updated_at
```

```sql
Vouchers Transactions
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id
user_id
voucher_id
created_at
updated_at
```

```sql
invoice
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id
order_data
payment_id
last_total
status
created_at
updated_at
```

```sql
Payment
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id
name
tax
created_at
updated_at
```

This is a query I made.

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.user_id, u1.name, u1.email, v.code, t.amount, t.type, t.created_at, t.invoice_transaction, i.status, p.name, 
FROM transactions AS t 
INNER JOIN users AS u1 on u1.id = t.user_id 
LEFT JOIN vouchers_transaction AS vt on vt.user_id = u1.id 
LEFT JOIN vouchers AS v on v.id = vt.voucher_id 
LEFT JOIN invoice AS i on i.order_data = t.invoice_transaction 
LEFT JOIN payment AS p on p.id = i.payment_id 
WHERE t.type = 'buy' 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

In this case I managed to get the data I wanted. But the results of the query contained duplicate transaction id data such as:

```sql
Result
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id              user_id             name                email                   code                amount              type                invoice_transaction             status              payment_name
1               1                   John Doe            John@mail.com           ycqs1               150                 buy                 SCS11DAS                        success             bank
1               1                   John Doe            John@mail.com           ycqs1               150                 buy                 SCS11DAS                        success             bank
2               1                   John Doe            John@mail.com           n1ksa               200                 buy                 SCS12DAS                        success             bank
```

**Update**

It seems like this happened because in the transaction voucher table there is no connection with the transaction table.

Example:

```sql
Voucher Transaction
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id          user_id             voucher_id
1           1                   1
2           1                   2
3           2                   3
```

Then each transaction will duplicate according to the number of vouchers used in the transaction vouchers, both transactions that use vouchers or not.

I know the best way is to change the database schema. But in this case can it still be done in this case or not?

Results

```sql
Result
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id              user_id             name                email                   code                amount              type                invoice_transaction             status              payment_name
1               1                   John Doe            John@mail.com           ycqs1               150                 buy                 SCS11DAS                        success             bank
1               1                   John Doe            John@mail.com           sa31a               150                 buy                 SCS11DAS                        success             bank
2               1                   John Doe            John@mail.com           n1ksa               200                 buy                 SCS12DAS                        success             bank
```

How do I ignore the duplicated transaction id?

Comment: Do you need a solution for  Microsoft SQL  Server **and** Postgres?

Comment: I only use Postgresql via linux terminal

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;
```

The `SELECT` `DISTINCT ON` statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

Comment: Still get the same ID

Comment: its should be `DISTINCT ON` for `postgresql`

Comment: I am got an error `Error in query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "t"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using group by

```
SELECT t.id, t.user_id, u1.name, u1.email, v.code, t.amount, t.type, t.created_at, t.invoice_transaction, i.status, p.name, 
FROM transactions AS t 
INNER JOIN users AS u1 on u1.id = t.user_id 
LEFT JOIN vouchers_transaction AS vt on vt.user_id = u1.id 
LEFT JOIN vouchers AS v on v.id = vt.voucher_id 
LEFT JOIN invoice AS i on i.order_data = t.invoice_transaction 
LEFT JOIN payment AS p on p.id = i.payment_id 
WHERE t.type = 'buy' 
GROUP BY SELECT t.id, t.user_id, u1.name, u1.email, v.code, t.amount, t.type, t.created_at, t.invoice_transaction, i.status, p.name
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always get double ID's because the rows are different. The code and amount columns are all unique and you havent told SQL what to do with those columns. The group by Mahesh showed will work, if you change it to resolve the difference in the code and amount columns.

what amount do you want to see for ID 1? The lowest? highest? average? sum?.

either you have to remove those 2 columns from the query, or provide an aggregate function to resolve what to show

Comment: can I take the last id of each transaction?

Comment: After I checked, several transactions occurred with the same ID but with different vouchers. This is because in my local development. If possible right I just want to take the max id of each transaction that the transaction? .

Comment: yes, you can use a cross apply instead of join. this will let you filter what you get as a return. im not entirely sure how the structure in your db works though. is there relation between voucher and transaction? or are both only linked with the user?

Comment: This voucher and transaction have no relation. I only relation both of them to users.

Comment: Select t.id, t.user_id, u1.name, u1.email, vt.code, t.amount, t.type, t.created_at, t.invoice_transaction, vt.status, vt.name, 
from users u1
cross apply(select top 1 * from transactions t where t.user_id = u1.id and t.type = N'buy' order  by updated_at desc) t
cross apply(select top 1 v.code, i.status, p.name from vouchers_transaction AS vt on vt.user_id = u1.id 
       LEFT JOIN vouchers AS v on v.id = vt.voucher_id 
LEFT JOIN invoice AS i on i.order_data = t.invoice_transaction 
LEFT JOIN payment AS p on p.id = i.payment_id 
where vt.user_id = u1.id
order by vt.updated_at desc) vt

Comment: Just remembered its postgres so cross apply wont work. You can use subqueries to get the same result. just get the last transaction per user first, and then get the rest of the columns

Comment: Alright I'll try it. Thank you for helping to explain it.